# Discrete Math sequence question

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

The question is find $a3$:
$a_0 = 2, a_1 = 4$ and $a_{k+2} = 3a_{k+1}-a_k$ for any integer $k \geq 0 $

I know the answer is 26, although how do you get the answer?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: The answer is always 42, right? In seriousness, what do you mean by "the answer"? I see no question only in the definition of a sequence by recursion...

Comment: There was an old quiz show in which an answer was given and one was supposed to give the question. Here it  is what is  $a_3$?

Comment: Yes sorry, it is to find a3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a_0 = 2,a_1 = 4,a_{k+2} = 3a_{k+1}-a_k$$

$$a_0=2$$
$$a_1=4$$
$$a_2=3\cdot4-2=10$$
$$a_3=3\cdot10-4=26$$
$$a_4=3\cdot26-10=68$$
$$2,4,10,26,68,...$$

Answer (score 0):

$ a_0 =2 , a_1 = 4, a_{k+2} - 3a_{k+1} +a_k = 0 $

We can suggest an equation that $ x^2 -3x +1 = 0 $,

Let the roots of the equation are $ x_1 , x_2$

then $x_1 +x_2 = 3$, $x_1 x_2 = 1$

then $a_{k+2} - 3a_{k+1} +a_k = 0 $$ \Leftrightarrow $ $a_{k+2} - (x_1 +x_2 )a_{k+1} + x_1 x_2 a_k = 0$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $ a_{k+2} - x_1 a_{k+1} = x_2 ( a_{k+1} - x_1 a_k) $

$\Rightarrow$ $a_{k+1} - x_1 a_k = x_2 (a_k - x_1 a_{k-1} )$

$\Rightarrow$ $a_{k+2} - x_1 a_{k+1} = (x_2)^2 (a_{k} - x_1 a_{k-1})  $

= $ \dots$ = $(x_2)^k (a_2 - x_1 a_1)$

also, $ a_{k+2} - x_2 a_{k+1} = (x_1)^k (a_2 - x_2 a_1) $

then $ (x_2 - x_1)a_{k+1}  = (x_1)^k (a_2 -x_2 a_1) - (x_2)^k (a_2 -x_1 a_1)$

then $a_{k+1} = \frac{(x_1)^k (a_2 -x_2 a_1) - (x_2)^k (a_2 -x_1 a_1)}{x_2 - x_1}$

$ \therefore  a_k = \frac{(x_1)^{k-1} (a_2 -x_2 a_1) - (x_2)^{k-1} (a_2 -x_1 a_1)}{x_2 - x_1} $